# evade deleted row of dataset in database table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, dataset

I dont know what to keep the heading (still confused, sorry for that). In my project, I am trying to update the database table through `DataSet`. Well I achieved this but when I delete any row in my `DataSet` and try to update the Database table then VS is showing error --> "Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row". Then I searched in Internet I got the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4321840). Now my code is not showing any error but to my exclamation the database is being updated with new values of `DataSet` both existing and **deleted too**. I dont want to add the deleted rows of `Dataset` to database table. How to solve this?

In my code I am using `DataRowVersion.Original`, should I change it? I also tried other values of `DataRowVersion` but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//yes before inserting values into database you have to put some check

```
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Table_Name"].Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                { 
                    // Perform insertion in to database
                }
                if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                { 
                    // perform updation in to databse
                }
            }
        }
```