# How do i delete a row from my dataset, using Rowstate and Delete()

Tags: c#, dataset, rowstate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row. (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321840/error-deleted-row-information-cannot-be-accessed-through-the-row-c)

I get this error when im trying to delete a row from my DataSet:

> Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row

How do i fix this.

Here is my function below:

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var result =  MessageBox.Show("Proceed to deleting this location?", "Delete Location", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
       if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
       {
            var row = myData.xspArea.FindByxar_Id(pRow.xar_Id);
            if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                row.Delete();
                MessageBox.Show("This location has been deleted", "Location Deleted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
       }
       else
       {
          this.Close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to call `mData.AcceptChanges()` after row.Delete().

Comment: @YaqubAhmad: `AcceptChanges` will prevent updates in database since the rowstate is what the datadapter uses to determine what to do with the row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `mData.AcceptChanges()` after row.Delete().

**EDIT:**

As @Tim Schmelter says:
`AcceptChanges` will prevent updates in database since the rowstate is what the datadapter uses to determine what to do with the row

Comment: `AcceptChanges` will prevent updates in database since the rowstate is what the datadapter uses to determine what to do with the row.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth reading the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx) to understand what `row.Delete()` is supposed to do.

> If the RowState of the row is Added, the RowState becomes Detached and
>   the row is removed from the table when you call AcceptChanges.
>
> The RowState becomes Deleted after you use the Delete method on an
>   existing DataRow. It remains Deleted until you call AcceptChanges. At
>   this time, the DataRow is removed from the table.
>
> A deleted row can be undeleted by invoking RejectChanges.

So, `row.Delete()` will change the `row.RowState` to `DataRowState.Deleted`.

If you want your row to actually be deleted from the DataSet, you need to call `row.AcceptChanges()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the exception is actually raised on `FindByxar_Id(pRow.xar_Id)` and not later on `row.Delete();`. Have you created a copy of the DataRow with `pRow` or is that row also deleted(maybe through cascade delete constraints)? Then you cannot access the `xar_Id` because it's already deleted.

So check this also:

```
// ...
if(pRow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
{
    var row = myData.xspArea.FindByxar_Id(pRow.xar_Id);
    if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    {
        row.Delete();
        // ...
    }
// ...
```

If you want to update the database you need to use a `DataAdapter`.