# Getting values from deleted rows in data grids using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I am using typed datasets with datagrids. When I delete a row I use the `dataset.HasChanges` filter and get changes as follows.

```
dtDel = (Database1DataSet1.product_skuDataTable)database1DataSet1.product_sku.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
```

I am trying to get values(Product Names) from deleted rows as follows.

```
private string getProdNames(DataTable dtDel)
{
    string prodNames = "";

    var q = dtDel.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ProductName"));

    foreach (string p in q)
    {
        prodNames += p + "\n";
    }

    return prodNames;
}
```

But I am getting the following error.

> Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c579f1c0-6389-4454-ac84-8a5447b9a107/accessing-deleted-row-information?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321840/error-deleted-row-information-cannot-be-accessed-through-the-row)

The linq query will work like this

```
 var q = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>(colName, DataRowVersion.Original));
```