# How to apply DataRowVersion.Original to Lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda

```
UltraGrid dgSomeGrid = new UltraGrid();


if (((someDS.someDT)dgSomeGrid.DataSource).Any(x => x.ColumnA == someCode))
{

}
```

The above code threw exception because one of the row was deleted, similar problem as posted earlier : [Error: Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321840/error-deleted-row-information-cannot-be-accessed-through-the-row).

According to the answer, solution can be checking the rowVersion so I'm wondering on how to apply `DataRowVersion.Original` to the above mentioned `Lambda` expression instead of looping?

Comment: Have you tried `...Any(x => x["ColumnA",DataRowVersion.Original]==someCode))`

Comment: @Pikoh `Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type string` ?

Comment: Tried but no luck `....Any(x => Convert.ToString(x["ColumnA", DataRowVersion.Original].ToString()) == someCode)`

Comment: What happens with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `DataRowVersion` you have to do it by accessing the `DataRow` collection. So this code should do:

```
if (((someDS.someDT)dgSomeGrid.DataSource)
                      .Any(x => x["ColumnA",DataRowVersion.Original].ToString()==someCode))
```

But you must be careful because if there is no DataRow versions (i.e. there has been an `AcceptChanges()` just before this code), this would throw an exception, so you'd rather check it:

```
DataTable dt=(someDS.someDT)dgSomeGrid.DataSource
bool r;
if (dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original)))
{
    r = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x["Column1", DataRowVersion.Original].ToString()==someCode);
}
else
{
    r = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x["Column1"].ToString()==someCode);
}
```

**Edit**

BTW, I think that a better solution is to just `AcceptChanges()` before your query, as it has little sense to search for values that has been already deleted.